# Animate CSS Overlay to FadeIn and FadeOut

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I have a css overlay that covers the entire viewport when a button is clicked. It fadesIn from `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1` using css keyframes.

The overlay is dependent upon a js plugin adding a class to the `<body>` element. So when that class is applied, the overlay is set to `display: block`

I'm trying to animate this effect in reverse. So when the class is removed, the overlay fades out.

I understand that I can apply multiple animations to the `.overlay` class, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Any ideas how I might reverse the animation?

```
.overlay {
  // Overlay base styles
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999999;
  cursor: pointer;

  // Set transition for overlay
  -webkit-transition:         all 425ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:            all 425ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:             all 425ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:              all 425ms ease-in-out;
  transition:                 all 425ms ease-in-out;


  // Set the animation duration
  -webkit-animation-duration:   1.1s;
  -moz-animation-duration:      1.1s;
  -ms-animation-duration:       1.1s;
  -o-animation-duration:        1.1s;
  animation-duration:           1.1s;

  // Set the animation fill mode
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:  both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:     both;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode:      both;
  -o-animation-fill-mode:       both;
  animation-fill-mode:          both;

  // Name the Animation
  -webkit-animation-name:       fadeIn;
  -moz-animation-name:          fadeIn;
  -ms-animation-name:           fadeIn;
  -o-animation-name:            fadeIn;
  animation-name:               fadeIn;
}

// When is showing class is applied
// make the overlay display block
.scotch-is-showing .overlay {
  display: block;
}

// Setup keyframes animations
// Chrome
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

// Firefox
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

// Opera
@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

// All other browsers
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking instead of using keyframe I could just add `opacity: 1;` to the class that shows the overlay, and `opacity: 0;` to the `.overlay` class then do a simple transition instead of an animation.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably utilize a helper class, and then toggle that class to trigger your animation.

Like this:

```
.overlay {
  // Overlay base styles
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999999;
  cursor: pointer;

  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition:         all 1.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:            all 1.1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:             all 1.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:              all 1.1s ease-in-out;
  transition:                 all 1.1s ease-in-out;
}
 .scotch-is-showing .overlay{
      display:block;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

You don't need key-frames since its just changing opacity from 0 to 1.

Toggle the `fadeIn` class using javascript. Adding it will fade in the overlay and removing it will fade it out.

using jQuery it might look like this:

`$('.overlay').toggleClass('fadeIn');`

**UPDATE**

I missed the part about the plugin and the `display` toggle. This should still work, you just don't have to worry about the javascript toggle. I have updated the css selector in the above css. `display` doesn't transition but opacity does.

Comment: Remember, the faded out overlay is still obstructing the viewport. You will also need to set a timed event to hide the layout.

Comment: @Myst I updated my response. I missed the part about the `display`